# android - TranslateAnimation from PointA to pointB

Tags: android, google-maps, android-animation

I would like to translate a view from pointA to pointB. imagine a line is drawn from pointA to pointB. the view should be translated to pointB along that invisible line. how a can i acheieve this. here is what i have tried so far:

```
getView().animate().translationX(deltaX)
getView().animate().translationY(deltaY)
```

but im not getting the results i want. to be specific i am using a google map and i want to move one marker to another location using translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [this repo](https://github.com/tintinscorpion/CarMarker-Animation) will help you achieve your desired goal.

> i am using a google map and i want to move one marker to another
>   location

I think the `animateMarker()` method in the [`MapUtils.java`](https://github.com/tintinscorpion/CarMarker-Animation/blob/master/MarkerAnimationExample/app/src/main/java/logicbeanzs/com/CheapRidedDrivernz/Utils/MapUtils.java) will help you achieve this,

```
public static void animateMarker(final Location destination, final Marker marker) {
        if (marker != null) {
            final LatLng startPosition = marker.getPosition();
            final LatLng endPosition = new LatLng(destination.getLatitude(), destination.getLongitude());

            final float startRotation = marker.getRotation();

            final LatLngInterpolator latLngInterpolator = new LatLngInterpolator.LinearFixed();
            ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);
            valueAnimator.setDuration(1000); // duration 1 second
            valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    try {
                        float v = animation.getAnimatedFraction();
                        LatLng newPosition = latLngInterpolator.interpolate(v, startPosition, endPosition);
                        marker.setPosition(newPosition);
                        marker.setRotation(computeRotation(v, startRotation, destination.getBearing()));
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        // I don't care atm..
                    }
                }
            });

            valueAnimator.start();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your way must be more complex to achieve this goal.
Need to draw a transparent cover that must be clickable and focusable to receive touch events and prevent map changes from user input (for example, FrameLayout or custom View) above MapView. And then draw a "fake marker" on this Surface, animate, and finally destroy them.

The trick is next:

1. You have a marker at point **A**
2. Show Surface above all map to prevent touch
3. Draw new view "fake marker" on this Surface (above original marker)
4. Remove the original marker from the map
5. Animate/Translate your new marker to point **B**
6. Draw a new marker on the map at point **B**
7. Hide Surface with "fake marker"

Comment: I'm just asking what to use for the coordinates. Everything else is working and I'm able to animate.  I have to points on the screen and I'd like to translate to it. Tell me what deltax etc would be. And what typeOf should I use. Ie animation.ABSOLUTE

Comment: oh you can draw new marker in point B, get their absolute coordinates on screen and delete marker B. Then translate marker A to coordinates that you get from trick above.

Comment: @j2emanue you can get deltaX & deltaY like this:
 int[] location = new int[2];
viewMarkerB.getLocationOnScreen(location);
int deltaX = location[0];
int deltaY = location[1];